# how to get the latest rows but with only one row for a given type, with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this (simplified):

```
(
    instrument     varchar   not null,
    ts             timestamp not null,
    status         boolean   not null,
    analysis_start timestamp not null,
    ...
)
```

I would like to get the rows for the last 5 minutes where status is true:

```
SELECT * FROM cookbook
WHERE status = true AND ts >= now() - interval '5 minute'
```

Ok, so far so good, but then I would like to have only ONE row of each instrument and it would have to be the most recent one:

[image]

In this example, I would only keep rows: 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (instrument) c.*
FROM cookbook c
WHERE status AND ts >= now() - interval '5 minute'
ORDER BY instrument, ts DESC;
```

Note that `status = true` is redundant; you can just use `status`.

Comment: ok, great thanks. What does the c.* do, vs. just *?

Comment: c is the alias to cookbook table and c.* means select everything from cookbook (which is c)

Comment: In this case, the output is the same because only one table is involved.

Comment: ok, I get it; as a beginner with SQL I keep getting confused by things used before they get defined, like the 'c' alias being defined after the c.* :)

Comment: @Thomas. . . It takes some getting used to, but the data references are defined in the `from` clause.